# Linear Recurrence for very large n

Tags: java, recurrence

I was trying to solve this problem on SPOJ (http://www.spoj.pl/problems/REC/)

`F(n) = a*F(n-1) + b` where we have to find `F(n) Mod (m)`
where

```
0 <= a, b, n <=  10^100
       1 <= M <= 100000
F(0)=1
```

I am trying to solve it with BigInteger in JAVA but if I run a loop from 0 to n its getting TLE. How could I solve this problem? Can anyone give some hint? Don't post the solution. I want hint on how to solve it efficiently.

Comment: You forgot one other piece of information from the problem: `F(0) = 1`. This question is also offtopic for SO - you might try for instance Math.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the pattern of residues mod (m) should have a repeating pattern in a linear recurrence, and with length <= m by the pigeonhole principle.  You need only calculate the first m entries, then figure out which of those entries will apply to F(n) for the actual value of n.

It also helps to solve a simpler problem.  Let's pick really small values, say a=2, b=1, m=5, n=1000.

- F(0) = 1
- F(1) = 2*F(0) + 1 = 2*1 + 1 = 3 -> 3 Mod 5 = 3
- F(2) = 2*F(1) + 1 = 2*3 + 1 = 7 -> 7 Mod 5 = 2
- F(3) = 2*F(2) + 1 = 2*7 + 1 = 15 -> 15 Mod 5 = 0
- F(4) = 2*F(3) + 1 = 2*15 + 1 = 31 -> 31 Mod 5 = 1
- F(5) = 2*F(4) + 1 = 2*31 + 1 = 63 -> 63 Mod 5 = 3
- etc.

Notice that the residues are [1, 3, 2, 0, 1, 3, ...], which will repeat forever.  So from this example, how would you determine F(1000) Mod 5 without looping all the way to the 1000th entry?

Comment: Oh!! That seems intuitive. I think I got you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll tell you how to solve a simpler problem. Suppose that b is zero. Then you just need to calculate a<sup>n</sup> mod M. Instead of multiplying n-1 times, use a divide-and-conquer technique:

```
// Requires n >= 0 and M > 0.
int modularPower(int a, int n, int M) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    int result = modularPower(a, n / 2, M);
    result = (result * result) % M;
    if (n % 2 != 0)
        result = (result * a) % M;
    return result;
}
```

So you can calculate a<sup>n</sup> in terms of a<sup>floor(n/2)</sup>, then square that, and multiply by a again if n is odd.

To solve your problem, first define the function f(x) = (a x + b) (mod M). You need to calculate f<sup>n</sup>(1), which is applying f n times to the initial value 1. So you can use divide-and-conquer like the previous problem. Luckily, the composition of two linear functions is also linear. You can represent a linear function by three integers (the two constants and the modulus). Write a function that takes a linear function and an exponent and returns the function composed that many times.